# Python-Selenium. Testing across different pages with POM

Tags: python, selenium, automation, permissions, pom.xml

First time posting here.

I'm currently working on automating UI tests using **Python** and **Selenium**, we also use **POM**(Page Object Model) in my workplace.

My team has asked me to do **a series of tests to verify user permission levels**. Let's say I have 3 pages: Homepage, Settings, and Albums. All users can view posts in HomePage, but only certain users will be able to change things in Settings or upload photos in Albums.

This would not be a problem if I needed to do it separately, but since I need to check what a user can or can't do and that requires visiting multiple pages and I imagine that involves multiple Page Objects.

My question is: **How can I approach this test if every page is in its own Page Object?** I thought about doing another class that manages each permission and the test to verify it, but I still encounter the problem with the multiple Page Objects.

I'm really lost about how to solve this, so much that I actually created this account haha.

**Thanks for your time!**

Comment: What exactly are you asking? POM is for multiple pages.

Comment: @DMart there are multiple pages in our application, that's why we use POM. The thing is my team wants to verify a user can do different things in multiple pages in one test, which I have never done, I would usually test one feature in just one page.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I am following you exactly, but I think you are referring to having to traverse multiple pages to check permissions per user/test. If you want to use POM, you can have the following Classes in your POM folder:

```
homepage
settings
albums
```

Different .py files per Class.

Not sure of the layout of your app, but let's assume there are links to `settings` and `albums` within the `homepage`.  In that case within your `homepage` class you would have (among other things) 2 methods, 1 returns an instance of the `settings` page, one returns an instance of the `albums` page.

Your test would then following something like this, for testing a users permissions on `albums`:

```
Go to Homepage -> execute method for returning albums page -> assert user can access page (or not access page)
```

There are a lot of areas you would need to fill in the blanks obviously, this is just very high level

EDIT:

Example below about how to return a Class object from another Class in Python, like I was mentioning.  This is taken from: https://willowtreeapps.com/ideas/organizing-automated-tests-with-page-object-model

```
def login(self, email, password):
        self.set_password(password)
        self.set_email(email)
        self.click_submit()
        return HomePage(self.driver)
```

In this instance you are in the login page/class and the login method is returning the HomePage class (taking you from Login to Homepage)

Comment: I was thinking something along the lines, but wouldn't making an instance of setting or albums in homepage result in the code being fragile? Is this some type of circular dependency? 
High level is fine, it gives me a nice direction :)

Comment: Not fragile at all.  Then again I am talking in C# terms where classes and objects are much more structured than Python.  Even if you didn't return an instance of the object (albums for example) in the homepage you could just have a method that takes you to the album page directly.  driver.find_element_by_xpath([some-element-that-takes-you-to-albums-page]) Then in the test you'd just run that method and assert the user can or cannot open that page

Comment: thanks! It looks like either I use instances of my classes and risk creating fragile code, or use no instances with the downside of having to rewrite code I might already have in those classes. 
If there's a better solution it's out of the scope of my current abilities, so this will have to do for now.
Again, many thanks!

Comment: Creating instances of your Classes is not fragile at all.  I just added a code example and a link.  Hopefully it makes sense